# Django: How to populate form data in Template using class based views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

My view is below:

```
class ListAndCreate(CreateView):
    model = xmpp_buddy_groups
    form_class = xmpp_buddy_groups_form
    second_form_class = sip_extension_form
    template_name = "xmpp/index.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('xmpp:index')
```

my form is below:

```
class xmpp_buddy_groups_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = xmpp_buddy_groups
      fields = ['group_name']

class sip_extension_form(forms.ModelForm):


   class Meta:
     model = SipExtension
     fields = ['sip_extension']
     widgets = {
            "sip_extension": forms.Select
           }
```

I want to populate data of sip_extension in template when I use form in template as {{form.as_p}}. But I have no clue how can I do that.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Purpose is same but language is better here. I can delete older question. @Alasdair

Comment: If you delete the other question then you lose all the comments from users who were trying to help you. Your new question isn't clearer. You still have the same problem: A model form is meant for creating or updating a single instance. It doesn't make sense to use it to select existing values of `sip_extension`.

Comment: So how can I assign a sip_extension to xmpp_buddy_group. I can already do that by updating a different form in extensions app in which I can assign groups to  extensions. But I want to do it vice versa too. @Alasdair

Comment: I can't help you in the comments of a closed question.